# How to remove "Be Careful! Parts of your Document may include personal information that can't removed by the document inspector" in excel by using c#

Tags: c#

When my c# program open an excel and run, the excel file will prompt a warning

```
"Be Careful! Parts of your Document may include personal information that can't removed by the document inspector"
```

[image]

In my c# automation project, I don't want users that involve in click these buttons too much. How can I remove this in c#?

Thanks.

Comment: I had browser this questions on google and get the same result like schufeli answered. However, I just want the program can remove the prompt by itself. Rather than deliver to the users, and let he do the below steps himself.

Comment: is your program creating the excel file, or does it work on an arbitrary excel file that can be created by anyone?

Comment: The excel file create by an authority, and I download from them. Then I need to pass this excel file and my c# program to a third person.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it's incredibly annoying and there's strangely little posted about it on the interwebs.  Anyway, here's how you fix it: Goto File in the upper left hand corner, then Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Privacy Options > then un-check the check box that says "Remove personal information from file properties on save", then hit OK.

"Borrowed" from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/be-careful-parts-of-your-document-may-include/fae98705-d078-4fc5-843a-908dda5be559)

Next time please use some more time to find a solution.. didn't even had to google 1 minute..

Comment: Sorry, seems you did not understand my questions. I want to use program do this by itself to let this prompt to disappear, rather than let users to do these steps as you mention before opening the program.

Comment: Just for clarification, who creates the excel file your software or the user?

Comment: Not my nor the user, the excel file created by an authority. I download the file from them, then I need to pass my c# program and this excel file to the user (a third person)

Comment: I don't see the point in chastising someone for not searching. Not to mention it is reasonable to ignore any microsoft community links when it comes to answers about their software.